# Observable rxjs filter

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

In my project, I wanted to create some sort of "Recommended Products" in each product page,
but having trouble with making my function filtering an observable.

I have tried using .pipe(filter()) in different ways, but to no use.

Basically the fucntion should filter products with the same **type** and **id**, and show them  in the proper product page, but pretty much got stuck after subscribing all of my products(which is marked down below).

Much Appreciated!

[image]

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../services/product.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, Router } from '@angular/router';
import  Product  from '../interfaces/product';
import { map, filter} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  recommandedProducts: Product[];
  allProducts:Product[];
  // allProducts:Observable< Product> = new Observable< Product>();
  product: Product;
  


  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private route: Router, private actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.findRecommendedProducts(this.product)
  };

//From ProductService:
//   getProducts(){
//    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}`);
//    }
  findRecommendedProducts(currectProduct: Product){
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
      this.allProducts = data;
      console.log(this.allProducts)
      this.recommandedProducts = this.allProducts.filter(otherProduct => 
      otherProduct.type == currectProduct.type && otherProduct.id == currectProduct.id)
      console.log(this.recommandedProducts);
    });      
  };



}
```

Comment: shows us the data which you are getting from service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filter in rxjs is not the same as an `Array.filter`. In rxjs, a filter is used to emit values that pass the provided condition. So if you use a filter, based on the condition, the observable will either emit your data or return nothing.

Instead, what you need is `pipe(map)` along with an `Array.filter`. Also, as @jzzfs pointed out, your error shows `currentProduct` could be `undefined`, so you can pass a default value in your `findRecommendedProducts` function.

Try the below code.

```js
findRecommendedProducts(currectProduct: Product = {} as Product) {
    this.productService.getProducts()
    .pipe(
        map((products: Product[]) => products.filter(product => product.type == currectProduct.type && product.id == currectProduct.id))
    )
    .subscribe((data: Product[]) => {
        this.recommandedProducts = data;
    });      
};
```

Now your subscribed data should directly return the `recommendedProducts`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, yet I get 2 new errors:

1.  Regarding currentProduct: Product = {}  :

     Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Product': product_Name, 
     product_Description, product_Price, product_Img, and 3 more.

For what its worth, I have a Product.ts file which Is imported to component.





    2. Regarding the .filter:

Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: @moses Both your errors are type assertion errors. `currentProduct` is of type `Product` so it cannot be an empty object. You can either add a default value for each parameter in `Product` or simply change `findRecommendedProducts(currectProduct: Product = {})` to `findRecommendedProducts(currectProduct: Product = {} as Product)`. The second error is weird. Is your `getProducts` returning a value of type `Object`? It should be returning a value of type `Product[]` instead. I tested this on StackBlitz using an array and it worked fine.

Comment: This is a type issue. I'm not saying your data isn't an array. Have you defined any return type in `getProducts` or in the `this.http.get`? It would help if you can add your `getProducts` code to the question too.

Comment: In my productService, getProdcuts() returns (copied 1 product out of 18):
[{"_id":"5e1c9fc052b6b1b6b8fee292","product_Name":"Soccer Ball","product_Description":"Soccer Ball","product_Price":10,"product_Img":"./assets/soccerball.jpg","id":0,"product_Quantity":1,"type":"soccer"}, .....}]

console.log(this.productService.getProducts()) returns: 
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
_isScalar: false
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: FilterOperator}
operator: MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project: ƒ}
__proto__: Object

Comment: getProducts(){
      return this.http.get(`${this.uri}`);
    }

Comment: Change `map(products => products.filter(product => product.type == currectProduct.type && product.id == currectProduct.id))` to `map((products: Product[]) => products.filter(product => product.type == currectProduct.type && product.id == currectProduct.id))`. I have edited my answer to show the changes.

Comment: It fixed the errors! :), but when I console.log(this.recommendedProducts) after subscribing, I get an empy array.
Why is that?

Comment: Well your filtering based on the value of `currentProduct` and initially it has no value. so the filter compares `undefined` with each `type` and `id` and gets no data. Initialize `currentProduct` with `type` and `id` which matches an object from your products and you should see the value.

Comment: I see..well currectProduct should return the type and id based on the product page. How would you suggest doing that?
Huge thanks for your assistance!!

Comment: Kindly stick to one issue per question. There is no relevant code or info for me to answer that question here. I don't know the interactions between your component, where your product page is, how these two components communicate or if they are separate components at all. I suggest opening another question for your issue. Kindly vote/accept if you find any answer helpful

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `currectProduct` passed onto `findRecommendedProducts` is `undefined`, since the logged `this.allProducts` do contain values.

With that being said, notice that when you define `product: Product`, you've only defined its type but you have not initialized it. The default value is therefore `undefined` -- if I remember correctly.

So change `product: Product` to `product: Product = {};`, for instance or pass a value to it within the constructor or within `ngInit`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it didnt help.

Comment: What's the value of `this.allProducts` and `currentProduct` then? Update your question if the data is too long.

Comment: this.allProducts recieves all of my 18 products(marked console above),
and currentProduct recieves no data, because as I said, the function doesnt
filter observable.